Need to group Great Grand parent , Grand parent , Father ,Child etc.....Records in single Row in spark
This is Source Data Frame



id
name
layer
parent
child




1
A
1

3


2
1
1

5


3
B
2
1
4


4
C
3
3
6


5
2
2
2
7


6
D
4
4



7
3
3
5




Need result in below way  in dynamic manner some time child's will be more (pyspark)



ID
NAME
CHILD1
CHILD2
CHILD3




1
A
B
C
D


2
1
2
3
NULL



Plz provide dynamic code in pyspark
i have below code but i feel this is static
        from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

        # Create SparkSession
        spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("Hierarchy DataFrame") \
            .getOrCreate()

        # Create DataFrame from the provided data
        data = [
            (1, 'A', 1, None, '3'),
            (2, '1', 1, None, '5'),
            (3, 'B', 2, '1', '4'),
            (4, 'C', 3, '3', '6'),
            (5, '2', 2, '2', '7'),
            (6, 'D', 4, '4', None),
            (7, '3', 3, '5', None)
        ]

        hie_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'name', 'layer', 'parent', 'child'])

        # Define DataFrames for each level
        parent_layer1 = hie_df.filter(hie_df['layer'] == 1)
        level2 = hie_df.filter((hie_df['parent'].isNotNull()) & (hie_df['layer'] == 2))
        level3 = hie_df.filter((hie_df['parent'].isNotNull()) & (hie_df['layer'] == 3))
        level4 = hie_df.filter((hie_df['parent'].isNotNull()) & (hie_df['layer'] == 4))

        # Join DataFrames and select the desired columns
        result_df = parent_layer1.join(level2, parent_layer1['id'] == level2['parent'], 'left') \
                                 .join(level3, level2['id'] == level3['parent'], 'left') \
                                 .join(level4, level3['id'] == level4['parent'], 'left') \
                                 .select(parent_layer1['id'], 
                                         parent_layer1['name'], 
                                         level2['name'].alias('child1'), 
                                         level3['name'].alias('child2'), 
                                         level4['name'].alias('child3'))

        # Fill NULL values with 'NULL'
        result_df = result_df.na.fill('NULL')

        result_df.show()


        from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

        # Create SparkSession
        spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName("Hierarchy DataFrame") \
            .getOrCreate()

        # Create DataFrame from the provided data
        data = [
            (1, 'A', 1, None, '3'),
            (2, '1', 1, None, '5'),
            (3, 'B', 2, '1', '4'),
            (4, 'C', 3, '3', '6'),
            (5, '2', 2, '2', '7'),
            (6, 'D', 4, '4', None),
            (7, '3', 3, '5', None)
        ]

        hie_df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'name', 'layer', 'parent', 'child'])

        # Define DataFrames for each level
        parent_layer1 = hie_df.filter(hie_df['layer'] == 1)
        level2 = hie_df.filter((hie_df['parent'].isNotNull()) & (hie_df['layer'] == 2))
        level3 = hie_df.filter((hie_df['parent'].isNotNull()) & (hie_df['layer'] == 3))
        level4 = hie_df.filter((hie_df['parent'].isNotNull()) & (hie_df['layer'] == 4))

        # Join DataFrames and select the desired columns
        result_df = parent_layer1.join(level2, parent_layer1['id'] == level2['parent'], 'left') \
                                 .join(level3, level2['id'] == level3['parent'], 'left') \
                                 .join(level4, level3['id'] == level4['parent'], 'left') \
                                 .select(parent_layer1['id'], 
                                         parent_layer1['name'], 
                                         level2['name'].alias('child1'), 
                                         level3['name'].alias('child2'), 
                                         level4['name'].alias('child3'))

        # Fill NULL values with 'NULL'
        result_df = result_df.na.fill('NULL')

        result_df.show()

